# Page content to not scroll off page (no iframe)

Tags: scroll

It’s difficult for me to word this question as I do not know the correct terminology. I’m trying to make a website so that when I scroll the main content, it does not scroll off the page. I want the main content to end somewhere in the middle of the page so as not to cover my “fixed” background image. But I do not want an iframe. In other words, it'll look somewhat like an iframe, but it should be controlled by the main scroll bar.

Anyway, I hope that made sense. I'd appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use two `<div>`s that will cover the top and bottom part so that your text will go underneath them.

```
+----------------+
|+--------------+|
||    top       ||
|+--------------+|
|  your text     |
|     text       |
|+--------------+|
||   bottom     ||
|+--------------+|
+----------------+
```

On the `z-index`, the `top` and `bottom` will be over the main layer, and they will be positioned `fixed` to the top-left corner and bottom-left corner.

HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/FE2Wg/3/

Comment: Thank you for all of your comments! iuliux, yes this is what I am wanting to do. Expect I only want the my content entry to scroll, using the main scroll bar. I am new to this, and I didn't know about JS fiddle before you left a link for me! Thanks. Anyway, I have added my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/callcan/9Nu5c/

Comment: But it does scroll using the main scroll bar. Could you please try and clean your code a bit, so you left only the relevant part, because is very difficult to work with, being quite messy. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry about that. I cleaned my code up. I will try to work with what you suggested in the last post. It is what I need, but I guess I'm just having trouble implementing it. I am still very new to this.

Comment: Can you give me a link to the new, cleaned up version, please?

Comment: I believe that this is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/YdURP/6/   I fixed your errors in HTML (try to indent your code so you don't forget to close or close too more tags).  You have there a new `footer` div added at the bottom, and the `menu` heavily modified. Also some other modifications (it is advised to use 100% instead of something like `1200px`. On a screen resolution of 1024*768 there will appear an ugly and unneccesary horizontal scroll bar)

Comment: Hope this helps! If it does, you can show your appreciation with upvotes and choosing an answer (green check sign)

Comment: Awesome! Yes, that is exactly what I've been trying to do for the longest time! Thanks so much! I appreciate your help and suggestions! And I'll give you a green check sign! And as this is my first time using stack overflow, I'll have to learn how to upvote. Hopefully, I'll get better at all of this soon! Hope to see you online again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you already using `background-attachment: fixed;` ?

Or `overflow-y: scroll;` with a div?

Comment: this will create a new scroll bar to his div, i believe

Comment: Indeed. Fixed background is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You want to show the scroll bar in a block of your HTML, right? Try using the CSS overflow property.

Reference: www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Try this in your page code:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
div.scroll {
height: 200px;
width: 300px;
overflow: auto;
border: 1px solid #666;
background-color: #ccc;
padding: 8px;
}
-->
</style>
<div class="scroll">
    <p>This is a scrolling are created with the CSS property overflow.</p>
    <p>This is a scrolling are created with the CSS property overflow.</p>
    <p>This is a scrolling are created with the CSS property overflow.</p>
    <p>This is a scrolling are created with the CSS property overflow.</p>
    <p>This is a scrolling are created with the CSS property overflow.</p>
    <p>This is a scrolling are created with the CSS property overflow.</p>
    <p>This is a scrolling are created with the CSS property overflow.</p>
    <p>This is a scrolling are created with the CSS property overflow.</p>
    <p>This is a scrolling are created with the CSS property overflow.</p>
    <p>This is a scrolling are created with the CSS property overflow.</p>
    <p>This is a scrolling are created with the CSS property overflow.</p>
    <p>This is a scrolling are created with the CSS property overflow.</p>
</div>
```

Is this you are trying to do??

Comment: No, I'm trying to get only the content entry to scroll using the main scroll bar. I don't want to have  a scroll bar in the middle of the page. Here is a link to the code I'm working with. http://jsfiddle.net/callcan/9Nu5c/